# .bat script utilising FFMPEG not running

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

FFMPEG .bat script not running when I double click on the script file. It tries to open for a millisecond, and then just disappears. My videos are in .MP4 format same as in the script.

Here is the script:

```
FOR /F *tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vf fade=in:0:d=5 -af afade=in:0:d=5 "%%~nG_1.mov"
```

And this is the result I am getting when I paste script to the CMD in folder:

```
*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vf fade=in:0:d=5 -af afade=in:0:d=5 "%%~nG_1.mov" was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: what happens when you open a `cmd` window and run your *script* from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo `*tokens=*"` should be `"tokens=*"`

try this

```bash
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vf fade=in:0:d=5 -af afade=in:0:d=5 "%%~nG_1.mov"
```

Comment: thank you very much mate, now it works, also I have one more script and it isnt running too.Is it possible for me to send it in here so you could check it please?

Comment: just ask a new question and, if i can, i will answer :) This is better for indexing and to help other users as well